# Repositories Method For Dropdowns

Tags: php, laravel, repository, repository-pattern, laravel-5

I've previously seen some methods for repositories where developers have a method for retrieving fields for preparing dropdowns inside of a form.
This is something I'd like to take advantage of with my application.
This is the logic  that I would use in multiple areas of my app for multiple entities.

It's something I want, but I can't get it.

Does anyone know of somewhere I can find this logic?

I've done some research, but I have not found it yet.
But I've seen it, somewhere.

Comment: What are you actually looking for? Can you provide a practical example? Most likely you'll need to setup your repository and either call the method from the repository directly from the controller (so it's passed onto the view) or you'll use a service to be in "the middle" between your controller and repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came across something that helped me. I've also included a link for anyone that might be looking for something like this.

http://blog.dannyweeks.com/web-dev/repositories-in-laravel-sharing-my-base-repository

```
/**
 * Items for select options
 * @param  string $data    column to display in the option
 * @param  string $key     column to be used as the value in option
 * @param  string $orderBy column to sort by
 * @param  string $sort    sort direction
 * @return array           array with key value pairs
 */
public function getForSelect($data, $key = 'id', $orderBy = 'created_at', $sort = 'DECS')
{
    return $this->model
                ->with($this->relationships)
                ->orderBy($orderBy, $sort)
                ->lists($data, $key);
}
```